Can anyone suggest a good external Wi-Fi adapter for Asus Vivobook 16 that works with Ubuntu 23.10?
I'm using Ubuntu 23.10 on an Asus Vivobook 16 (X1605VA-MB957WS), which uses a Mediatek Wi-Fi card whose driver is not supported by the kernel of Ubuntu. So I don't have Wi-Fi.
Can anyone suggest a good external Wi-Fi adapter so that I can have Wi-Fi on my laptop?
The output of lshw -C network is:
*-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:6000000000-60000fffff memory:84000000-84007fff

The output of lspci | grep -i network is:
0000:02:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7902

I saw an online post claiming that TP-Link USB Wifi TL-WN725N works but that adapter doesn't have a driver for kernel version > 4.4.3, so I'm not sure if it'll work or not.

Check your system firmware is 100% current and if it is not, update it. (This ought to be a FAQ.)

@LiamProven It is up to date

So it is on version 315? A new BIOS came out in March.
https://www.asus.com/laptops/for-home/vivobook/vivobook-16-oled-x1605/helpdesk_bios?model2Name=Vivobook-16-OLED-X1605

If not, get that. Once you've done it, attach to an Internet connection via Ethernet and try the Ubuntu Software & Updates tool. It should tell you if it needs any special drivers, then download them.

Your question in its current form has some issues, so it cannot be really answered. In fact it should be closed as being not focused. You see, each question should focus on one issue only, while you need help for three unrelated issues (one of them (the first) is a hardware recommendation, which is also off-topic). Have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions So, to keep your question open and possibly get some answers, please [edit] it to focus only on one issue and post a new question for each other issue you face. For the hardware question, please try https://superuser.com

Thanks for the recommendations @BeastOfCaerbannog

@HarshalChaware You're welcome! Note however that the question now is a hardware recommendation, which is off-topic here as I said above. This is the question that you should ask in Super User. I'm going to edit your question and then feel free to copy-paste it there.
